# How to change the minimum touch contact diameter on android OS?

Tags: android, touch

I think that smallest contact diameter that will register on android tablets is 6-8 millimeters. Is a way to make the minimum touch contact smaller than 6 mm programmatically or otherwise? And How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague.  Do you want to enlarge touch targets throughout the entire system from a piece of java code, do you want to globally enlarge touch targets throughout an application, or would you be happy simply enlarging touch targets for some of the onscreen controls in your application?

If you'd like to do the latter, you should take a look at the [Android TouchDelegate class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html).  It  allows you to create a "delegate" view which accepts touch input on behalf of another view.  The onscreen area covered by the delegate can be much larger than the original view.

Comment: I'd actually like to make it smaller, around 2mm, in an application.

Comment: Missed that part.  Not sure if you can do that with TouchDelegate, but you could put up a static image of something, then layer in an invisible View centered over it and smaller than the image.  Then put a click handler on the invisible View.